# Building RStudio from sources: javac error

Tags: r, compiler-errors, rstudio, java

I want to build RStudio on my Linux Mint 18 Laptop. I have both openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-9-jdk installed, and I use the following code to compile the package:

```
git clone http://github.com/rstudio/rstudio.git
cd rstudio
mkdir build
cd dependencies/linux 
./install-boost
./install-qt-sdk
./install-dependencies-debian
cd ../../build
cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

But then I try:

```
sudo make install
```

and get an error:

```
[javac] error: Source option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[javac] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It seems that you need to use a newer version of Java, version 1.6 or later.

Comment: So, it is a problem with java, not with makefiles?

Comment: It seems to be. Just go on Oracle's website, and download the most recent version of Java (8).

Comment: I've just tried another diagnostic tool. It's seems, you are right.

Comment: I believe the issue is actually related to the use of openjdk-9-jdk specifically to build RStudio. If I understand correctly, that version of the OpenJDK doesn't support Java source targets for version 1.5. See e.g. http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/182

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Logan Kulinski: openjdk from standard distribution has too old version of Java, so I had to install Oracle version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webup8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```